# CoverFlow with Button and Image

Tags: android, button, click, coverflow

I am using overflow in my application, within adapter, if i set gravity of button at top then click works fine, but if i set gravity bottom then click does not work, seems area shown is different from the one actually drawn. Because if i click outside button (2-3 px above button) then its click event triggered but not on button.

Within overflow I have Image and Button.

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    tools:src="@drawable/image_1"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"/>
```

Here is my main layout

Please help

Comment: pest your entire xml file , menu file and the screen which you get in out put ri8 now

Comment: I downloaded from here https://github.com/moondroid/CoverFlow
In this I want button at the bottom of every image and that button should be clickable.

Comment: you have to customize few things in library ,and with out see full code we can not able to give you exact solution at which you should change in library project.